# Permission issue in Yii Framework and Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yii, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a web application using yii framework in PHP, and hosting it to the Google App Engine. When i run the application using Google App Launcher on localhost. It's working fine but when i am deploying it to the Google App Engine, It showing me an error

**"Error 500 
Application runtime path "/base/data/home/apps/s~thegaumsy/1.XXXXXXXXXXXXX/webapp/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process"**

I am working on windows 7. Please suggest me solutions for windows only.

Thanks.

Comment: Applications in appengine can't write to the local filesystem. Any PHP code that attempts to do so will fail - hence the error you are getting. This has nothing to do with your local system (windows) but a designed in restriction of the appengine runtime.

Comment: Here is a solution: https://github.com/poul-kg/yii-app-engine

Comment: @HarryFink you should rewrite your comment into an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Rahul Gautam did you get success in solving your issue & How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

http://github.com/poul-kg/yii-app-engine

Never tried it personaly.

Comment: This is working. But didn't get solution for the Specific Error. What i need to change it to make it run

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user [poul-kg](https://github.com/poul-kg) on GitHub, all you need is the [CSyslogRoute](https://github.com/poul-kg/yii-app-engine/blob/master/webapp/protected/components/CSyslogRoute.php) component. Make sure you import CSyslogRoute.php so you can use the class in your configuration file under the log application component.

```
    // applicaion components
    'components'=>array(

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CSyslogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    )
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is still showing me the same error.Imported CSyslogRoute in components and changed in main.php.Can you please help